# MongoDB Compass connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

The default localhost connection refused.

- Operating System: Windows 7
- MongoDB Compass: Version 1.19.12

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgJjA.jpg)

Comment: Does it accessible on the terminal/command prompt?
if yes then open your mongod.cfg file then check 
net:
   bindIp: 127.0.0.1
   port: 27017
Use that port to open in your MongoDB editor

Comment: Check if Mongodb is running first of all, I would usually suggest running `sudo service mongod status`, however, I believe this won't work in windows, but I'm sure there's something equivalent in the docs

Comment: Thanks, Mohammad and Lucas, when I update my MongoDB Compass to 1.20.3 version the problem resolved.

Comment: Seems mongod is not running. Please check once

Answer (score 12):

Type services in start.
open it.
search for mongodb there.
start/restart the mongodb from services.

Answer (score 3):

This message shows that your mongo is disconnected.
Therefore you should open your cmd (Windows)
Then type `mongod and press Enter key.
After a few minutes, mongo will be connected.
Then connect through your MongoDB Compass

Answer (score 2):

reinstall mongodb as network service. it works for me.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a Mac user and I hit this error while using MongoDb compass, but I solved this by checking IP address in `mongod.config` (which is located by default on Mac at `/opt/homebrew/etc/` if you used homebrew to install it) and launching the server using this config file.
To make it sure I set the following config (ip address depending of what you set up in you `hosts` file too):

```
net:
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1,0.0.0.0
  port: 27017
  ipv6: false
```

Then even if I was in the folder which contains the config file, I had to specify the config file in order to start the mongodb service with the following command line:

```
mongod --config mongod.config
```

Then I was able to connect through MongoDb Compass.

Hope this help Mac users who are seeking answers and maybe also Windows users because you might also need to specify that config file even if you are the MongoDb Server folder.

Answer (score 2):

Seen so much stuff for Windows but on mac I just ran

```
brew services start mongodb-community
```

Comment: bro question is for windows, what's the use of this response

Answer (score 1):

must you need to run MongoDB server on local? for that, you need to:

- run a command on the command prompt. open command prompt goes to a file location like `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin`.
- type `mongod` and press Enter key.

After a few minutes, mongo will be connected. then add path variable to the environment.

Comment: I can't see MongoDB folder in Program Files after installation of mongodb-compass-1.36.3. Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1):

This issue arises due to the following reasons:

- MongoDB is not installed completely.
- System env variables do not contain a path for MongoDB.

**Solution**

- Reinstall MongoDB and select complete setup to install all the associated packages of MongoDB.
- Type in the Windows search bar for system environment variables, select environment variables and look for the "Path" in the System Variables list.
- Click on the path and add a new path for MongoDB by browsing in the system where the MongoDB folder is saved and select the bin folder in the MongoDB directory.
- Open cmd and type mongod, this will start MongoDB services.
- Now your Mongo Compass should connect and not throw a refused error.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using windows and getting this error
Follow this:

- Search Services   Find Mongodb Server   Click on it Click on the
  start It will start local service for you.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, follow the steps below:

1. Windows button + R
2. type "services" and press Enter,
3. Find "MongoDb", right click and select "Start"
4. Go back to MongoDBCompass, and try again to connect to localhost.

Answer (score 0):

you should create a file for saving data;please take attention to  the erro infomation in  power shell,follow the infomation and you will solve it.
add the file  ,for example:"D:/data/db"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you need to check the status of your localDB ,this command is for ubantu

```
=>sudo systemctl status mongod
```

check the status and start your local DB

```
=>sudo systemctl start mongod
```

using this command I'm able to connect my local as well as mongo compass.